# How to escape @ in Ant SCP task

Tags: ant, escaping, sftp, scp

I would like to ask you for some help. How can I use an scp task when my username contains an @ sign?

I tried to escape the character in many ways but it isn't working. In the following example, my username is user@host.com

```
<scp file="test.txt" todir="&quot;user@host.com&quot;:password@ftp.host.com:/" trust="true" sftp="true"/>
<scp file="test.txt" todir="'user@host.com':password@ftp.host.com:/" trust="true" sftp="true"/>
<scp file="test.txt" todir="user\@host.com:password@ftp.host.com:/" trust="true" sftp="true"/>
```

But the output is always the same:

```
neither password nor keyfile for user "user has been given.  Can't authenticate.
```

Please, is there anyway to force the task to parse this string correctly? Thank you very much.

By the way, I don't know why but with my current provider it is impossible to create a username without appending the hostname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the SCP task in my build.xml and it's form looks like this:

```
<scp file="package/ROOT.war" todir="user@example.com:~" trust="true" password="${password}"/>
```

Looking at the [source of the SCP Task](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/ssh/Scp.java?view=markup) at the function `parseUri(String uri)` (line 370) it appears that the task can support a username with a @ symbol.  The restrictions appear to be with paths that have a : or @ in them as seen by this comment:

```
// user:password@host:/path notation
// everything upto the last @ before the last : is considered
// password. (so if the path contains an @ and a : it will not work)
```

The code doesn't seem to support this comment (as pointed out by 
[martin clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183172/martin-clayton)).  You can also see the error you are referring which is triggered when the password or the keyfile is missing.  Maybe the combination of a password in `user:password@host:/path` notation and a username with an @ is causing problems?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am sure that my username contains the @ sign. I have only Windows now. But when I am using any GUI app (like WinSCP or TotalCommander) the connection works. And yes, I have to use SFTP connection instead of SCP. I read the docs (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) and passwords can be passed both ways. But both ways is not working

Comment: And when I connect via TC, I see in the header: user@host.com@ftp.host.com

Comment: This thread http://www.iprodeveloper.com/forums/aft/53169 talks about an incompatibility with older versions of scp and sftp and usernames with @ symbols in them. They offered escaping with \@ or upgrading the server. Does any of this help?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I found this forum and tried these escaping possibilities (mentioned in question) and they does not work. I think that I don't have problem at server side. I can connect with other clients. I think it is Ant scp client that parses it incorrectly. Now I get this error: java.net.UnknownHostException: host.com@ftp.host.com , but the host is only ftp.host.com.

Comment: It looks like an Ant bug to me.  The line above the comment you quote shows the fault - it assumes that the first colon in the uri will always be _before_ the first @, but when the @ appears in the username, this is not the case.  The alternate logic in the if doesn't support this case either.  Needs a little rewrite.

Comment: I hadn't read it to that depth, I assumed the "last @" part was handled by some other code, but now that you point it out it's true.  I updated the answer to include your point.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The problem is at line 347: int indexOfAt = uri.indexOf('@'); This way it never goes through next condition (indexOfColon < indexOfAt) for my case. And it processes it as URI without password. I've made some tests and I think the line 347 should be changed to: int indexOfAt = uri.lastIndexOf('@');. This way it parses correctly all cases I tried...

Answer (score -1):

Present ant version `-1.9.4` operating system:-`16.04 Ubuntu` did not work.

Changed to `1.9.3` and pointed to `/usr/bin/ant`  ssh was successful
observation:

```
16.04 and ant 1.9.3 is working
14.04 ant 1.9.4 is working
```