# How to escape @ in username in ant scp task

Tags: ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to escape @ in Ant SCP task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979503/how-to-escape-in-ant-scp-task)

I try to copy files from local to remote using ant scp with jsch. My problem is, that my username contains "@" and I don't know how to escape. I tried @@, set the username as property and give the username as command argument. Nothing helped. Ant tries to reach the false server.

It work's on filezilla and Apatana. Can anyone help me?

To understand my problem here is an example. 
My username is auth_user@maschine_user@maschine

```
<scp file="example.txt" 
todir="auth_user@maschine_user@maschine@host:/targetdir" 
keyfile="priv_id_dsa"
passphrase="XXXXX"
sftp="true"
/>
```

Thanks a lot!